# Get a List of Type of All Fields and Their Methods in A Case Class

Tags: scala

I have a simple case class defined as follows:

```
case class Foo(f1 : String, f2:String)
```

I would like to use reflection to query a the `Foo` type for all it's declared fields, get the type of those fields, and then get the methods associated to those types. So in this example, it would get the fields `f1` and `f2` and then for those fields it will determine their type, in this case `String` and then get all the methods associated to the `String` type.

I tried the following:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> case class Foo(f1 : String, f2:String)
defined class Foo

scala> ru.typeOf[Foo].declarations
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res30: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = SynchronizedOps(value f1, value f1, value f2, value f2, constructor Foo, method copy, method copy$default$1, method copy$default$2, method productPrefix, method productArity, method productElement, method productIterator, method canEqual, method hashCode, method toString, method equals)
```

First question is why `f1` and `f2` appear twice in this list?

I couldn't get at the types of `f1` and `f2` here so I tried

```
scala> ru.typeOf[Foo].getClass.getFields
res31: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(public final scala.reflect.api.Universe scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi.$outer)
```

But this doesn't look like it's retrieved the fields `f1` and `f2`.

How can I achieve what I need with scala reflect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question is why f1 and f2 appear twice in this list?

Both field and its getter method.

> ru.typeOf[Foo].getClass.getFields

`typeOf[Foo]` returns a `Type`. So `typeOf[Foo].getClass` will return a class which implements `Type`, not `Foo`. Just write `classOf[Foo].getDeclaredFields`. Or if you want to use scala-reflect types:

```
ru.typeOf[Foo].declarations.collect { 
  case t: TermSymbol if t.isCaseAccessor => t 
}
```